# Set a collection as a sub-collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm wondering if there's a more straightforward way to set a collection as a sub-collection in a new document. My current method is:

1. Get `CollectionA`, which will be used as the sub-collection
2. Create a ref to new `DocA`
3. Set some data into `DocA`
4. Create a ref to new `CollectionB` in `DocA`
5. Use a `batch()` and loop through `CollectionA`, using `batch(set, CollectionA.doc.data())` on each doc of `CollectionA`
6. `batch.commit()` to commit all the docs from `CollectionA` into `CollectionB`

Is there a simpler way to accomplish this?

Like:

```
DocA.collection('CollectionB').set(CollectionA)
```

I've tried a few methods similar to this but `CollectionA` ends up living in a single doc within `CollectionB`. Instead of all the docs within `CollectionA` becoming docs within `CollectionB`.

Comment: Are you asking whether you can create a new document and subcollection in one call? The answer to that is "no". If you're asking whether it's possible to create a subcollection without creating the document it's in, the answer is "yes": `db.collection('CollectionB/document1/CollectionA').add(...)`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the steps though. Are you trying to duplicate all documents of a collection in its subcollections? If so: why? I'm all for data duplication, but at first glance that sounds a bit excessive.

Comment: Basically I want a snapshot (as in current state, not in the sense of Firestore snapshot) of `CollectionA`, to set as a sub-collection in `DocA`. In other words, I want to save `CollectionA`s state, as a sub-collection of  `DocA`, when `DocA` is created.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I don't think there's any faster way to do that then by copying them in batches. Note that a batch can contain no more than 500 write operations, so you may have to perform multiple.

Comment: `CollectionA` contains ~12 docs, but the docs are nested objects/arrays. For querying/updating I think it's more useful as a sub-collection opposed to a nested object containing arrays. So the `batch` isn't too much trouble in this case, but wanted to make sure there wasn't a simpler way.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Can you post the above as a solution so others can quickly find the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to duplicate documents from one collection into another. You will have to read the documents to a client, and then write them into the target collection.

I don't think there's any faster way to do that then by copying them in batches. Note that a batch can contain no more than 500 write operations, so you may have to perform multiple.